# A python HTTP server does not accept connections

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out why `curl http://localhost:2113/healthz` fails with `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

main.py starts a HealthServer:

```
from healthServer import HealthServer

if __name__ == '__main__':
  HealthServer().start()
```

healthServer.py defines HealthServer as a thread which serves HTTP with a handler that derives from BaseHTTPRequestHandler:

```
from configuration import config
from http.server import HTTPStatus, HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import logging
from threading import Thread

class HealthHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        '''Respond to a GET request.'''
        if self.path == '/healthz':
            logging.info('GET /Healthz')
            self.send_response(HTTPStatus.OK)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(b'ok')
        else:
            logging.error('health endpoint received a GET for path {}'.format(self.path))
            self.send_response(HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND)
            self.end_headers()

class HealthServer(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        port=config['server']['ports']['healthz'].get()
        logging.info('Starting HTTP server on port {} to serve health on /healthz'.format(port))
        httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', port), HealthHTTPRequestHandler)
        httpd.serve_forever()
        logging.warning('health server exited')
```

Starting the application logs
`Starting HTTP server on port 2113 to serve health on /healthz`.

Comment: Works fine for me if I take out the few lines involving `config` and just hard code `port=2113`.  `http://localhost:2113/healthz` gives `ok` in browser and `127.0.0.1 - - [23/Oct/2020 13:47:47] "GET /healthz HTTP/1.1" 200 -` in PyCharm console. - I should note that I put both code snippets in the same file so I could use my standard scratch area where I test arbitrary code.

Comment: I think your main thread is just exiting after starting the http server, and so the whole app dies. You can .join() your server thread to wait for it, or just don't use a thread for server at all (just use main thread).

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything to have your main ending not have the whole program stop.  I didn't change anything, and it doesn't quit on me.  As long as you don't mark your thread as a daemon thread, the system will wait until the thread exits to stop the program.  There's nothing special about the main thread.

Comment: Interesting, I've also copied everything into one file and hardcoded the port. Start the app, point curl at it, get back 'ok'. I think my problem must be coming from docker then. I normally run this inside docker and port forward with -p 2113:2113 in the docker run command, then it doesn't work. Investigating...

Comment: Indeed, docker problem, nothing wrong with this app. If I docker exec onto the container and curl, it works. Not sure what's going on but this isn't a python question for SO anymore. Thank you!